# How can I collapse and expand the recycler view layout when the button is clicked?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am developing a recycler view with Kotlin. Let's look at my code, when I click on the orderProduct button, the orderRecyclerview is visible and on the contrary, when I click again, the visible is gone. But sometimes when I click on it, the recycler view is shown and sometimes it is not shown.
So how can I do this anytime? How can I solve this bug?

```
 orderProduct.setOnClickListener{

            orderProduct.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, if (!isClicked) R.drawable.btn_down else R.drawable.btn_up, 0)

                if (isClicked) {

                    var r = Runnable {

                        try {
                            orderRecyclerview.visibility=View.VISIBLE
                            paymentList= paymentDb?.paymentDao()?.getAll()!!
                            mAdapter = PaymentRecylcerViewAdapter(this, paymentList)
                            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

                            orderRecyclerview.adapter = mAdapter
                            orderRecyclerview.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
                            orderRecyclerview.setHasFixedSize(false)

                        }catch (e: Exception) {

                        }
                    }
                    val thread = Thread(r)
                    thread.start()

                }else {
                    orderRecyclerview.visibility=View.GONE
                }

            isClicked = !isClicked

            }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, you can move this code above the `onclickListner`.

```
 paymentList= paymentDb?.paymentDao()?.getAll()!!
 mAdapter = PaymentRecylcerViewAdapter(this, paymentList)
 mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

 orderRecyclerview.adapter = mAdapter
 orderRecyclerview.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
 orderRecyclerview.setHasFixedSize(false)
```

Then inside the `onClickListner` handle visibility of `orderRecyclerview`.

For better user experience, You can also add animation in this.
Hope, it will help.

Answer (score 0):

add Dependecy
 `compile 'net.cachapa.expandablelayout:expandablelayout:2.9.2'`

```
  <net.cachapa.expandablelayout.ExpandableLayout
android:id="@+id/expandable_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:el_duration="1000"
app:el_expanded="true"
app:el_parallax="0.5">

<RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:text="Fixed height" />
```

```
To trigger the animation, simply grab a reference to the ExpandableLayout from your Java code and and call either of expand(), collapse() or toggle().
```

Comment: thank u for comment, I just add that method to xml. can u fix my java code ?

Comment: ExpandableLayout e=findViewById(R.id.expandable_layout);  e.expand(); //to expand layout, e.collapse(); //to collapse, e.toggle(); //to trigger the toggle